# What is a function $f(n)$ such that $t_n \in \Theta(f(n))$

Tags: computational-complexity

Let $t_n$ be defined as follows:

$$
t_n = \frac{571}{98}*7^n - \frac{45}{14}*5^n +\frac{6}{7}*n*5^n
$$

I am looking for a function $f(n)$ such that $t_n \in \Theta(f(n))$.

I am confused at how I can find the $\Theta$

Can you please guide me?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: the biggest bound is $n*5^n$ and the lower bound is $5^n$. As I understand it, the $\Theta$ is a function that bound t(n) on the upper and lower side. but I can't see it here

Comment: How about $f(n) = t_n$?

Comment: $7^n > n5^n$ pretty quickly.

Comment: @DavidP sorry for my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A, B, C$ be positive constants. Then since:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A \cdot 7^n - B \cdot 5^n + C \cdot n 5^n}{7^n} = A
$$

it follows that $t_n \in \Theta(7^n)$.

Comment: Thank you. Can we therefore always use the biggest term of a function $t_n$ or it depends on the cases?

Comment: Usually. In general, $f(n) + g(n) = O(\max\{f(n), g(n)\})$.

Comment: yes but in the case of $\Theta$?